# Updating two virtual table in WinRT under one transaction

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm creating a plugin under Cordova framework targeting Win10 (UWP), so my project is in WinRT. I'm using SQLite3 successfully, I have the reference for the SQLite.Net.Core-PCL and SQLite.Net-PCL (v3.1.1), and added the SQLite3 for my Win10 project, using the SQLite.UWP.2015 version 3.13.0.
I have to do some work on a given database with virtual tables, but whenever I want to update some row from 2 different virtual table in a single transaction, my application exit without throwing any exception, here is what i got if i don't run it from VisualStudio2015:

[SQLite error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYJqF.png)

```
Assertion failed!
Program: ..\sqlite3.dll
File: tsrc/fts3.c
Line: 3772
Expression: assert( ((Fts3Table *)pVtab)->mxSavepoint < iSavepoint );
```

I've tested when this throws, I created a simple example, creating two virtual table, inserting some data, and in next transaction i'm updating the two data, the first one is ok, but the second one throwing me out from the application.

```
        var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.db");
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.BeginTransaction();
                conn.Execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE T1 USING fts4(ID,VALUE)");
                conn.Execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE T2 USING fts4(ID,VALUE)");
                conn.Execute("INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('1','VALUE')");
                conn.Execute("INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('2','VALUE')");
                conn.Commit();

                conn.BeginTransaction();
                conn.Execute("UPDATE T1 SET  VALUE =  'value2'  WHERE  ID =  '1'"); //Everything is fine
                conn.Execute("UPDATE T2 SET  VALUE =  'value2'  WHERE  ID =  '2'"); //Fail
                conn.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Error occured while executing " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I found the rows in the fts3:
https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite/blob/master/ext/fts3/fts3.c

```
/*
** The xSavepoint() method.
**
** Flush the contents of the pending-terms table to disk.
*/
static int fts3SavepointMethod(sqlite3_vtab *pVtab, int iSavepoint){
  int rc = SQLITE_OK;
  UNUSED_PARAMETER(iSavepoint);
  assert( ((Fts3Table *)pVtab)->inTransaction );
  assert( ((Fts3Table *)pVtab)->mxSavepoint < iSavepoint );
  TESTONLY( ((Fts3Table *)pVtab)->mxSavepoint = iSavepoint );
  if( ((Fts3Table *)pVtab)->bIgnoreSavepoint==0 ){
    rc = fts3SyncMethod(pVtab);
  }
  return rc;
}
```

If I'm running in release mode, i don't get this error, because this assert are excluded from there, and as i see, the rows are modified successfully, but in debug mode, throws me out always.

I have to use all this in one transaction, because if some of them fail, I have to rollback everything.

Do you have any idea, how to resolve this, or why this happening?